# A newly added MessageContract doesn't appear in the service reference metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, messagecontract

I have a MessageContract called Document that looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Document : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public bool IsUploaded = false;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is fine for the most part. It shows up in intellisense and I can instantiate it just fine. But I needed to add a new contract that looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Dummy
{
    public int DummyID;
    public Image DummyImage;
    public int PageNumber;
}
```

Seemed simple enough. I built the project and updated my service reference. But that class doesn't show up and I can't instantiate it.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392309/wcf-service-metadata/1396311#1396311).

Only the types actually used by the service will be reflected in the metadata.

I didn't have an operation contract that used the DataContract. I didn't need to have one at the time, so I didn't make it. But apparently, unless you have one that uses it, the metadata won't be generated for that DataContract.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have not declared where the DummyId, DummyImage and PageNumber will be put. either in the Message body or in the message header.More details on the usage of message contracts are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx).

Comment: I had previously added [MessageBodyMember] and [MessageHeader] tags and nothing changed.