# WCF - WSDL not updating when publishing service

Tags: c, wcf

I added a DataContract to my service and tried updating the service reference to get access to that DataContract. But it never showed up in the intellisense. I cleaned and built the project and then updated the service reference, but it still didn't work.

I then published it to the server and updated the service reference so it would point to the server, but I get the same thing. I browsed the service through IIS and opened my service in the browser.

I clicked the top link that had Service.svc?wsdl to see if my DataContract was there. An old MessageContract was there, but the DataContract was not.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396311/1339826).

> Only the types actually used by the service will be reflected in the metadata.

I didn't have an operation contract that used the DataContract. I didn't need to have one at the time, so I didn't make it. But apparently, unless you have one that uses it, the metadata won't be generated for that DataContract.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the currently deployed service binaries and verify that the service is inaccessible.   Then deploy the new service binaries.  This is to verify you're actually deploying to the correct location.

It is also possible that the service binaries aren't being rebuilt.  To verify this, delete your bin folder (located next to your project file generally) and issue a rebuild, then follow the first steps.

Comment: I just all of that and I'm afraid it didn't work. It's still not generating it.

Comment: My last thought would be to restart visual studio.  If you haven't, I would double check that all of your WCF-related attributes are correctly applied.